# about #ifndef and macro_function

Tags: arrays, c, function, macros, ifndef

i have changed complier from msvc to mingw,

macro function : `_countof` was not inluded in mingw <stblib.h> or <stdio.h>

```
#define _countof(array) (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))
```

maybe it's only for msvc,

so,i have to add the defination into header file myself,

i'm not sure about the code below:

```
#ifndef _countof(array)
#define _countof(array) (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))
#endif
```

It seems that this way of writing is not common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underscore prefix indicates that it is proprietary and not and ISO standard name.

It is the macro *name* that is tested in `#ifndef`, so just:

```
#ifndef _countof
    #define _countof(array) (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))
#endif
```

Though personally I prefer:

```
#if !defined _countof
    #define _countof(array) (sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array))
#endif
```

Also a macro is just a macro.  There is no such thing as a *macro function*, rather you might refer to a *function-like macro*, being a macro that takes arguments, but even then semantically they are very different from functions.